# Creating HMAC-SHA-256 algorithm with a 128-bit key

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

I'm struggling with this for a while now. I scanned pretty much all there is on google but I just can't find the right script, how to create a HMAC-SHA-256 algorithm with a 128-bit key.

It should be as simple as this:

```
$algo = 'sha256';
$file = 'file.txt';
$key = '1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef';
echo hash_hmac_file ($algo, $file, $key );
```

`file.txt` contains only 8 zeros ( *00000000* ).

The output has to be **FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880**, but I just can't understand how?

I have tried multiple hashing algorithms, but none of them return the necessary value. What am I doing wrong here and how to fix it?

I tried also [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php#109409) solution, but it still comes out wrong.

I need this for connection with a bank and they provide [these test data](http://www.bgc.se/Default____8758.aspx) to start with.

---

Final answer:

```
echo 'FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880<br />';
$algo = 'sha256'; $file = 'file.txt'; $key = '1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef';
echo substr( strtoupper( hash_hmac_file( $algo, $file, pack("H*" , $key) ) ), 0, 32 );
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to create a crypted mac from the example 8 zeros so that it comes out exactly as `FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880`

Comment: Maybe key should be treated as hex bytes not as string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key needs to be converted from hexadecimal to binary data. Add:

```
$key = hex2bin($key);
```

And also make sure that you `file.txt` does *not* contain any trailing character like new line or carriage return.

Edit: The function [hex2bin](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) was introduced in PHP 5.4.0. For older versions you can use instead

```
$key = pack("H*" , $key);
```

Comment: **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function hex2bin() ... I'm using php 5.3

Comment: @DainisAbols you must be using a PHP version older than 5.4.0. I edited the answer to give an alternative.

Comment: Thanx m8, I found the answer: `pack("H*" , $key)` for php < 5.4